# Lottie animation subview of UIRefreshControl appears off-center

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, lottie, uirefreshcontrol

I am currently implementing a custom UIRefreshControl using a square Lottie animation. I have been wrestling with the autolayout constraints for the Lottie subview to my UIRefreshControl. I would really appreciate any advice. **I am trying to make my imported (json) animation be the same size and in the same position as a standard, vanilla Apple UIRefreshControl** with the following code:

```
    lazy private var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
    let rf = UIRefreshControl()
    rf.tintColor = .clear
    
    let loadingAnimation = Animation.named("My_Animation")
    let lottieView = AnimationView(animation: loadingAnimation)
    lottieView.play()
    lottieView.loopMode = .loop
    
    lottieView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    lottieView.frame = rf.bounds      
    rf.addSubview(lottieView)

    return rf
}()
```

**My issue is that this causes my animation to be left of center as opposed to centered in the UIRefreshControl parent view.** I tried using constraints such as:

```
lottieView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rf.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        lottieView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rf.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    lottieView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rf.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    lottieView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rf.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Also in other tutorials and posts, I've been seeing people suggest turning off translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints, but when I do so, the animation blows up larger than the screen and appears mostly off-screen.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this, I subclassed UIRefreshControl and called the following constraints in override init(). Seems to have fixed the issue:

```
    func setupLayout() {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    animationView.frame = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX - 160, y: 0, width: 320, height: 60)
}
```